# Move a Filestream column between tables

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I have a table which has a `Filestream` column which I would like to move to another table.

Is this possible without having to do a "manual" move of the data (create target column; issue `UPDATE/INSERT` to target column from source column; `DELETE` source column)?

I'm hoping there might be a way to simply "detach" the column and move it to a different table.

I found a similar/related [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72611/change-rowguidcol-property-to-a-different-column) about altering `Filestream` tables which makes me think that it isn't possible, but hoping that someone might be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't move the column without copying the data. There's one rather exotic idea to pull this of: You move *all other columns* and leave the filestream column in place.

Depending on the number of rows and schema changes required this can be a lot faster (or slower). You might have to completely gut some tables and create complicated scripts. I only would do this approach if you really need to avoid this downtime.

Comment: I like your backwards thinking :) I am going to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't know any way to do this. Just make an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on the other table. You can detach whole partitions of a table and move them to another table. But not just one column.

Why don't you just want to copy/move the data?

Comment: Because the column contains many GB of data and I don't want to have an upgrade path that takes hours!

Comment: Well many GB, how many? If you have a good IO subsystem it should be a operation of a few seconds maybe some minutes. I needed to move a table between two servers for a while which holds 200GB and it took 8 Minutes. Well many GB is relative. :-) And as I said, I haven't seen a way to perform such a operation.

Comment: Ranging from 50GB up to 400GB...But some of this is on customer infrastructure... I suppose you are right - I need to run  a test and see!

Comment: Ah ok. The customer side may vary. You can run a test by just moving 1000/10000 rows and try to evaluate how long it takes. By the way, if the customer side is set to `RECOVERY MODE SIMPLE`, I would suggest to run it in a loop and copy just 10.000 rows each time. If something fails, you won't rollback everything, just the last 10.000 rows. Another side-effect is that the transaction log won't grow to a huge monster in this case.